# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server error 26 on stimulsoft Report

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stimulsoft

I use this connection string in my asp.net

```
<add name="DB_PersonnelEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=REGAPP\SQL2014;initial catalog=DB_Personnel;user id=personnel;password=qwe123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and this code for StimulSoft

```
string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_PersonnelEntities"].ConnectionString;
string serverlocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Empty);

StiReport mystireport = new StiReport();
mystireport.Dictionary.Databases.Add(new Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiSqlDatabase("DB_PersonnelEntities", connectionstring));
mystireport.Load(serverlocation + "\\Report\\RptPersonnel.mrt");
mystireport.Dictionary.Variables["pid"].Value = id.ToString();
StiWebViewer1.Report = mystireport;
mvList.SetActiveView(vwReport);
```

The connection string works properly in all SQL connections of the program, except for Stimulsoft Report with the code shown above.

**Note**: this code and connection work properly for StimulSoft SQL connection and other sql connections on my PC and run from Visual Studio, but when the program is published on the server, the StimulSoft SQL connection shows an error 26.

I changed the connection string like this

```
<add name="Conn" 
     connectionString="Data Source=REGAPP\SQL2014;Initial Catalog=DB_Personnel;User Id=personnel;Password=qwe123!"   
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and changed instance name / disabled firewall / checked user permission for procedure.

THANKS FOR HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StimulSoft Save connection string (in Report.mrt file)  That created on my PC. When I Publish My Program, The StimulSoft report Use the connection string embedded in Report.mrt file **NOT** the web.config.

Answer (score 1):

The connection string you showed is an **Entity Framework** connection string, which I'm pretty sure a third-party reporting tool won't be able to use.

But embedded in that EF connection string is a "raw" ADO.NET connection string - have you tried that??

```
<add name="Report_PersonnelEntities" 
     connectionString="Data Source=REGAPP\SQL2014;Initial Catalog=DB_Personnel;User id=sa;password=qwe123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Word of warning**: it is generally recommended ***NOT*** to use the `sa` (system administrator) account which can do literally **everything** on your server for any programmatic database work - especially not for reporting! Create your own reporting user in SQL Server and use that instead of the all-powerful system admin account!

Comment: َAbout "raw" ADO.NET connection: I use a connection like this:<add name="Conn" 
     connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-UJVP6AL\APRON;Initial Catalog=DB_IFNApron;User Id=sa;Password=@pron$"   
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Just for the comment on the `sa` account this gets a +1. You need to fix that if you really are using that `LOGIN` @BehzadKeimasi .

Comment: sa is just Example I use another user "personnel"  thank you

Comment: @BehzadKeimasi: I saw that other connection string - but it uses different server and database name - maybe it's just those wrong settings that are the cause of the trouble you're having?

Comment: my question Code Edited, they are the same, I need The correct format of SQL Connection String that Accepted For StimulSoft thanks